# Pyomo KeyError: "Error accessing indexed component: Index '0' is not valid for array component 'li_f_inv'"

Tags: pyomo

I was trying to run the following code on Pyomo. It is a simple Transmission Expansion problem using a concrete model.

Thanks jsiirola. I am actually just learning Pyomo, thats why I might be making silly mistakes. I implemented all you suggested as shown below:

```
from pyutilib.misc import import_file
from pyomo.environ import *
import networkx as nx

model = ConcreteModel() 
model.name = "DTEPM_trial_concrete"

#Sets
#Epoch
model.E = Set(initialize = [0, 1, 2, 3])
model.E_n = Set(model.E, initialize = {0:[1,2,3,4,5], 1:[6,7,8,9,10], 2:[11,12,13,14,15], 3:[16,17,18,19,20]})

#System nodes
model.N = ['N1', 'N2', 'N3']
model.n_name= Param(model.N, within = Integers)

#T = Set()
model.G = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3']
model.LI = ['L1', 'L2', 'L3']

#Scalar Parameters
model.int_rate = 0.05
model.vll = 3000
model.tau_period = 8760

def R_discount_inv_init(model, i):
    return sum(1 / (1 + model.int_rate)**(i - 1) for i in model.E)
model.cum_disc_inv_cost = Param(model.E, initialize = R_discount_inv_init)

def R_discount_op_init(model, i):
    for index in model.E_n:
        return sum(1 / (1 + model.int_rate)**(i - 1) for i in model.E_n[index])
model.cum_disc_op_cost = Param(model.E, initialize = R_discount_op_init)

#Demand Periods
model.t_demand = {'N1': 1.05, 'N2': 2.10, 'N3': 7.35}
model.demand_curtailed = Var(model.E, model.N, within = NonNegativeReals)

#Generation Units  

model.ge_max = {'G1': 2.00, 'G2': 2.00, 'G3': 7.35}

model.ge_marginal_cost = {'G1': 30, 'G2': 35, 'G3': 40}

model.B = {('N1','G1'): 1, ('N1','G2'): 0, ('N1','G3'): 0, ('N2','G1'): 0, ('N2','G2'): 1, ('N2','G3'): 0, ('N3','G1'): 0, ('N3','G2'): 0, ('N3','G3'): 1,}

#Transmission lines
model.li_x = {'L1': 0.2, 'L2': 0.2, 'L3': 0.2}
model.li_max_f = 1.50
model.li_f = {'L1': 1.00, 'L2': 1.00, 'L3': 1.00} 
model.li_sending_bus = {'L1': 'N1', 'L2': 'N1', 'L3': 'N2'}
model.li_receiving_bus = {'L1': 'N2', 'L2': 'N3', 'L3': 'N3'}
model.li_length = {'L1': 100, 'L2': 100, 'L3': 100}

#Expansion Options
model.inv_cost_var = 4000000


nodes = ['N1', 'N2', 'N3']
edges = [['N1', 'N2'], ['N1', 'N3'], ['N2', 'N3']]
I = nx.DiGraph()
I.add_nodes_from(nodes)
I.add_edges_from(edges)

model.I = -nx.incidence_matrix(I, oriented=True) # this returns a scipy sparse matrix

#Variables

#Transmission line power flow limits
def fl_inv(model, i, l):
    return (0, model.li_max_f)
model.li_f_inv = Var(model.E, model.LI, bounds = fl_inv)

#Transmission line investment and operation contraints
model.f = Var(model.LI, model.E, initialize=0)
def fl_rule(model, l, j, i):
    if i:
        return model.f[l,j] >= -(model.li_f_inv[j,l] + model.li_f[l])
    else:
        return model.f[l,j] <= (model.li_f_inv[j,l] + model.li_f[l])
model.bound_f = Constraint(model.LI, model.E, [0,1], rule=fl_rule)

#generation limit
def fg(model, i, g):
    return (0, model.ge_max[g])
model.ge_output = Var(model.G, model.E, initialize = 0, bounds = fg)

#phase angles for the nodes
model.theta = Var(model.E, model.N, within = NonNegativeReals)

def line_equation(model, e, l):
    return model.bound_f[l] == (1/model.li_x(l) for l in model.LI) *(sum(model.theta[n] for n in model.N if model.n_name[n] == model.li_sending_bus[l]) - sum(model.theta[n] for n in model.N if model.n_name[n] == model.li_receiving_bus[l]))
model.line_equation = Constraint(model.LI, model.E, rule = line_equation)


def system_balance(model, e, n):
    return sum(model.b[n, g] * model.ge_output[g] for g in model.G) \
           + sum(model.I[n, l] * model.f[l] for l in model.LI) \
           - sum(model.t_demand[n] - model.demand_curtailed[n]) == 0

model.SystemBalance = Constraint(model.E, model.N, rule=system_balance)

#OBJECTIVE FUNCTION
def objective_mincost(model):
    return sum( model.cum_disc_inv_cost[e] for e in model.E * sum (model.li_f_inv[l] * model.inv_cost_var[l] * model.li_length[l]) + model.cum_disc_op_cost[e] * (model.tau_period * (sum(model.ge_max[g] * (model.ge_marginal_cost[g])) + sum(model.demand_curtailed[n] * model.vll)))) 
model.objective = Objective(rule = objective_mincost, sense = minimize) 

opt = SolverFactory('gurobi')
results = opt.solve(model) # solves and updates instance
model.display()
```

But received the following new error message:

ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint line_equation with index ('L3', 0):
        KeyError: "Error accessing indexed component: Index 'L3' is not valid for array component 'bound_f'"
ERROR: Constructing component 'line_equation' from data=None failed:
        KeyError: "Error accessing indexed component: Index 'L3' is not valid for array component 'bound_f'"

Please what do you think might be wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As the error indicates, you are not passing valid indices to `model.li_f_inv` in the rule for `model.f`.  Your Var `model.li_f_inv` is declared as:

```
model.li_f_inv = Var(model.E, model.LI, bounds = fl_inv)
```

Your current rule for `model.f` is only passing a single index to `model.li_f_inv`, which is invalid.  That means your rule for `model.f` needs to be updated to pass the correct indices:

```
#Transmission line investment and operation contraints
model.f = Var(model.LI, model.E, initialize=0)
def fl_rule(model, l, j, i):
    if i:
        return model.f[l,j] >= -(model.li_f_inv[j,l] + model.li_f[l])
    else:
        return model.f[l,j] <= (model.li_f_inv[j,l] + model.li_f[l])
model.bound_f = Constraint(model.LI, model.E, [0,1], rule=fl_rule)
```

Also note that you are transposing the indexing sets between the definition of `model.f` and the sets implied by the `fl_rule` function.

---

EDIT: I failed to notice that in your original post, you were attempting to use variables (`li_f_inv`) in the bounds of another variable (`f`).  This isn't a valid math program (not to mention, not valid Pyomo).  You need to express the variable bounds as a Constraint.  Also, while Pyomo allows you to express range constraints (`lb <= body <= ub`), both `lb` and `ub` must not be potentially variable.  Since that is not the case here, you must express the two bounds constraints separately.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I tried what you suggested I got the following error message: ERROR: Constructing component 'f' from data=None failed:
        TypeError: '_SumExpression' object does not support indexing                                                                                                  what else do you suggest I do. Thank you

Comment: Thanks jsiirola. I am actually new to Pyomo and hence might make some silly mistakes. I implemented all you suggested but getting a new error message as shown below: ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint line_equation with index ('L3', 0):
        KeyError: "Error accessing indexed component: Index 'L3' is not valid for array component 'bound_f'"
ERROR: Constructing component 'line_equation' from data=None failed:
        KeyError: "Error accessing indexed component: Index 'L3' is not valid for array component 'bound_f'"